# Get MD5 hash of image using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

actually I have a file, and I want to convert to MD5.

```js
{data: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAAGQCAYAAACAvzbMAAAAAX"
fileName: "test.png"
fileSize: 159000
height: 400
isVertical: true
originalRotation: 0
path: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.png"
type: "image/png"
uri: "content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ftest.png"
width: 400
}
```

I tried with these libraries:

- `import md5 from 'md5'`

but when is executed return me this: `3449c9e5e332f1dbb81505cd739fbf3f`

but when I executed: `MD5 test.png` in my Mac return me this: `01fd1175378be2d58dae81d934a5fe82`

I need the md5 of file because the API I need to use, require this.

but when I use the result of the library(`3449c9e5e332f1dbb81505cd739fbf3f`) return me error.
but when I use the result of my mac(`01fd1175378be2d58dae81d934a5fe82`) return me succesful.

so, I want to know how I can convert this file to `MD5` like terminal of my mac.

this is my all code of component

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'
import ImagePickerRN from 'react-native-image-picker'
import md5 from 'md5'
//? components
import { Text, IconButton } from '../'

//? styles
import styles from './styles'

const ImagePicker = ({ onValueChange, ...otherProps }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState()

  const selectImage = async () => {
    ImagePickerRN.showImagePicker((image) => {
      if (image.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker')
      } else if (image.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', image.error)
      } else if (image.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', image.customButton)
      } else {
        const source = { uri: image.uri }
        console.log({ md5: md5(image) })
        setImage(source)
        onValueChange(image)
        // You can also display the image using data:
        // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} {...otherProps}>
      <Text bold style={styles.text}>
        Image:
      </Text>
      {image ? (
        <Image source={image} style={styles.image} />
      ) : (
        <IconButton
          icon='picture-o'
          style={styles.image}
          iconStyle={{ fontSize: 70 }}
          onPress={selectImage}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

export default ImagePicker
```

Comment: You may just need `md5(image.data)`

Comment: Calling it on the `image` object isn't going to work. I think @jdaz has the right idea here, do it on the data and *only* on the data.

Comment: @jdaz, @tadman I did, but return me this: `9498d0b0418eb777b0c8847b30e4eed1`

Comment: Where is your `data` coming from? `"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAAGQCAYAAACAvzbMAAAAAX"` is much too short to be a base64 representation of an entire image

Comment: @jdaz I will add all base64

Comment: @jdaz. you can access to the all base64 here: https://www.miblocdenotas.com/360104
is too long, so, I cant add to this post

Comment: Actually it may be easier to use the [md5-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5-file) library instead of `md5`, because `md5-file` accepts file paths while `md5` does not. Then you can do `md5File.sync(image.uri)` to get your answer

Comment: I will try @jdaz

Comment: I tried to use the library you suggest me, but immediately show me a screen red with: `Unable to resolve module crypto from node_modules/md5-file/index.js`